# Use DATE_ADD to complete tstamp column

Tags: mysql, dateadd

I hope you guys had a good Christmas!
I was wondering, is there a way to use or apply COALESCE when the column is a tstamp? 
So that when the tstamp is like this:

```
|       tstamp          |
| 2014-12-25 00:01:00   |
| 2014-12-25 00:02:00   |
| 2014-12-25 00:05:00   |
| 2014-12-25 00:07:00   |
| 2014-12-25 00:08:00   |
```

I thought if i use coalesce hen i could fill in the missing time and get the tstamp column to look like this:

```
|       tstamp          |
| 2014-12-25 00:01:00   |
| 2014-12-25 00:02:00   |
| 2014-12-25 00:03:00   |
| 2014-12-25 00:04:00   |   
| 2014-12-25 00:05:00   |
| 2014-12-25 00:06:00   |   
| 2014-12-25 00:07:00   |
| 2014-12-25 00:08:00   |
```

is it possible? and is it even right to use COALESCE to get my desired output? suggestions is always appreciated. thank you

---

Update:

I think I can use something like DATE_ADD and do it like this

```
SELECT DATE_ADD('2014-12-25 00:00:00', INTERVAL 1 MINUTE)
```

but I'm not exactly sure how to get it to work cause when i executed that query i only got one row..

```
SELECT DATE_ADD('2014-12-25 00:01:00', INTERVAL 1 MINUTE)
```

any ideas? thank you

Answer (score 0):

NO, it's not possible cause that's not the right use of `COALESCE()` function. [`COALESCE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) function is used to select/get first `NON NULL` value from the provided list of values as argument.

Comment: oh ok what should i use instead?

Answer (score 0):

If you populate a column named `tstamp` into a table (call it mydb.mytable) with every minute today, you could do something like this

First make a query that generates every minute in a day

```
SELECT H*60+HRMIN MINVAL FROM
(SELECT  0 H UNION SELECT  1 UNION SELECT  2 UNION SELECT  3 UNION
SELECT   4   UNION SELECT  5 UNION SELECT  6 UNION SELECT  7 UNION 
SELECT   8   UNION SELECT  9 UNION SELECT 10 UNION SELECT 11 UNION 
SELECT  12   UNION SELECT 13 UNION SELECT 14 UNION SELECT 15 UNION 
SELECT  16   UNION SELECT 17 UNION SELECT 18 UNION SELECT 19 UNION 
SELECT  20   UNION SELECT 21 UNION SELECT 22 UNION SELECT 23) A,
(SELECT MT*10+MU HRMIN FROM
(SELECT 0 MT UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION
SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5) AA,
(SELECT 0 MU UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2
UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5
UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8
UNION SELECT 9) BB) B ORDER BY MINVAL;
```

Change it to create every minute today

```
SELECT DATE(NOW()) + INTERVAL H*60+HRMIN MINUTE MINVAL FROM
(SELECT  0 H UNION SELECT  1 UNION SELECT  2 UNION SELECT  3 UNION
SELECT   4   UNION SELECT  5 UNION SELECT  6 UNION SELECT  7 UNION 
SELECT   8   UNION SELECT  9 UNION SELECT 10 UNION SELECT 11 UNION 
SELECT  12   UNION SELECT 13 UNION SELECT 14 UNION SELECT 15 UNION 
SELECT  16   UNION SELECT 17 UNION SELECT 18 UNION SELECT 19 UNION 
SELECT  20   UNION SELECT 21 UNION SELECT 22 UNION SELECT 23) A,
(SELECT MT*10+MU HRMIN FROM
(SELECT 0 MT UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION
SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5) AA,
(SELECT 0 MU UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2
UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5
UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8
UNION SELECT 9) BB) B ORDER BY MINVAL;
```

Now, insert them into the table

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO mydb.mytable (tstamp)
SELECT DATE(NOW()) + INTERVAL H*60+HRMIN MINUTE MINVAL FROM
(SELECT  0 H UNION SELECT  1 UNION SELECT  2 UNION SELECT  3 UNION
SELECT   4   UNION SELECT  5 UNION SELECT  6 UNION SELECT  7 UNION 
SELECT   8   UNION SELECT  9 UNION SELECT 10 UNION SELECT 11 UNION 
SELECT  12   UNION SELECT 13 UNION SELECT 14 UNION SELECT 15 UNION 
SELECT  16   UNION SELECT 17 UNION SELECT 18 UNION SELECT 19 UNION 
SELECT  20   UNION SELECT 21 UNION SELECT 22 UNION SELECT 23) A,
(SELECT MT*10+MU HRMIN FROM
(SELECT 0 MT UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION
SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5) AA,
(SELECT 0 MU UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2
UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5
UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8
UNION SELECT 9) BB) B ORDER BY MINVAL;
```

I used `INSERT IGNORE` in case there is an already existing minute.

**Give it a Try !!!**